# Best way to make search full width

Tags: css, bootstrap-table

First time using this component, and I am looking to make the search input box full width.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Is it plain CSS, or is there an option in the script?

Here is my current script that generates the table

```
   initializeBootstrapTable() {
            let $table = jQuery(this.$refs.table);

            jQuery.fn.bootstrapTable.columnDefaults.formatter = function(value, row, index) {
                if(typeof(value) === 'boolean') {
                    return value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                }

                if(value === 'ug') {
                    return 'UG';
                }

                if(value === 'pg') {
                    return 'PG';
                }

                return value;
            };

            $table.bootstrapTable({
                data: this.applicants,
                showColumns: true,
                toolbarAlign: 'right',
                buttonsAlign: 'right',
                pagination: true,
                search: true,
                iconsPrefix: 'fa',
                icons: {
                    paginationSwitchDown: 'fa-collapse-down icon-chevron-down',
                    paginationSwitchUp: 'fa-collapse-up icon-chevron-up',
                    refresh: 'fa-refresh icon-refresh',
                    toggle: 'fa-list-alt icon-list-alt',
                    columns: 'fa-th icon-th',
                    detailOpen: 'fa-plus icon-plus',
                    detailClose: 'fa-minus icon-minus'
                }
            });

            $table.on('click-row.bs.table', (e, row) => this.handleApplicantSelection(row));
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: ...target the input and make the `width:100%` - done.

Comment: unfortunately, that isn't working, which is why I'm posting this question. I can make it "full width" if I specify a px size like 1135, but I'm looking for a more responsive way of doing this with this code.

Comment: Why is it not working though? Is there CSS that overwrites it? Have you inspected it to see whats going on with the CSS?

Comment: it's already getting width 100% for .form-control, which is calculated out to 186 px.

Comment: Alright, so it's the pull-right that's causing the problem. Is there a way to prevent the code from generating it with pull-right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option to remove the float, it's either choose left or right looking at the options. Instead, add the BS4 no float class. JS is a good approach here.

Vanilla:

```
var d = document.getElementById("my-search");
d.className += " float-none";
```

jQuery

```
$("#my-search").addClass('float-none');
```

Plain CSS

```
#my-search {
  float:none;
}
```

If you must, you can use the `!important` rule too.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!